# how to do live update or synchronized in vba

Tags: vba

how to do live updates to one cell to another cell?? I don't know, is it call synchronized or live updates, what im trying to do, i want my cell to update to another sheet, if i change something or values in sheet1 cell 1 then sheet2 cell 1 should change it automatically.. any1 have any ideas ????do i have to do live change or live updates or its a synchronizing or how do i code it, i never did anything like that before.....

```
sub worksheet_change()
    if sheets("sheet1") = sheets("sheet2") then
        do liveupdate
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: you mean use a formula? like `=Sheet1!A1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DDE**

If it's on the same computer, you can do something called DDE and make DDE based functions.

DDE is an old but still very well used technology (especially in the financial industry) which stands for Dynamic Data Exchange. That will enable you to control values in the cells of one worksheet from code driven through another.

Search for DDE examples, DDE MSDN, etc. and you'll find tonnes of simple examples out there.

**DCOM ??**

For a while, MSFT wanted to extend DDE and similar technologies across networks, like Distributed COM but security issues got in the way and common sense prevailed.

**RTD**:

A bit more involved and better (IMHO) method is creating a simple RTD server (Real Time Data Server) that reads data from your sheet, and pumps it across a network or simply to another instance of Excel on your computer.

Either of these methods can be used to distribute live stock feeds, etc. coming onto expensive subscription terminals across a network (be aware of the licensing issues though for spreading any data around using these techniques).

RTD information can also be found with simple examples to set up an RTD server scattered across google search results.

Hope it was helpful.